# CallLongMethod JNI Android SIGSEGV

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault

First of all, thank you for your time and help.

I'm making an Android + JNI app that tries to reach a 10 position array of Mat (openCV type).
I'm following this tutorial: [Pass an array of Mats to native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012115/pass-an-array-of-mats-to-native-code/17664292#17664292)

But when I get at the "CallLongMethod" line, it throws a SIGSEGV error. I've checked and non of the pointers (getPtrMethod, bufimgsfieldid, bufimgsArray) are 0. The code is here:

```
jmethodID getPtrMethod = env->GetMethodID(matclass, "getNativeObjAddr", "()J");
jfieldID bufimgsfieldid = env->GetFieldID(thisclass, "bufImgs", "[Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;");
jobjectArray bufimgsArray = (jobjectArray)env->GetObjectField(thisobject, bufimgsfieldid);

Mat* nativeBufImgs = new Mat[10];
LOGD("Creation Passed");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    LOGD("Makint the  %i", i);
    nativeBufImgs[i] = *(Mat*)env->CallLongMethod(env->GetObjectArrayElement(bufimgsArray, i), getPtrMethod);
}
```

Any idea of whats going wrong?

Comment: Maybe `CallLongMethod` returns 0?

Comment: Enable [Extended Checking](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking) to get more information.